# How to display banner ad in the bottom of all pages in my android application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, mopub, scringo

I am having banner ad in the bottom of the home page as below,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/background"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/bg" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/riverLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/navBar"
        android:background="@drawable/item_bg"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/riverImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/river_image_desc" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/riverImage"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="@string/river_text"
            android:textColor="#4494CA"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <com.scringo.ScringoCommentButton
            android:id="@+id/riverCommentButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/riverImage"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp" />

        <com.scringo.ScringoLikeButton
            android:id="@+id/riverLikeButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/riverCommentButton"
            android:layout_below="@id/riverImage"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/riverFeedButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/riverLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="@string/river_button_text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/openChatRoomButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/riverFeedButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/discover" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/openInboxButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/openChatRoomButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/open_inbox_button_text" />

    <com.scringo.ScringoLeftRibbonButton
        android:id="@+id/activationRibbonLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="350dp" />

    <!--
        <com.scringo.ScringoRightRibbonButton
        android:id="@+id/activationRibbonRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="350dp" />
    -->
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/toplayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView
        android:id="@+id/adview"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/spacer_old"  />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The banner ad view

```
'<com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView   ../>'
```

should display in all pages something like static/fixed at the bottom of each page of the application, that means i should not add this view in all the pages but still it should display at the bottom of all the pages(like image poping up from the bottom).
How to do this

Comment: anybody please give solution to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `android:layout_alignParentBottom` attribute from `com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView` to its parent `RelativeLayout` as below

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/toplayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView
        android:id="@+id/adview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/spacer_old" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: in the present code the banner view is displayed in the bottom itself, my problem here is even if another xml/layout loads by starting another activity, this MoPub view should keep displaying at the bottom and the remaining new page/layout sholud be displayed above this Mopub view

Comment: then you will have add this XML snippet with every `Activity` layout XML.

Answer (score 0):

or try this

```
    <com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView
        android:id="@+id/adview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/spacer_old" />
</RelativeLayout>
    android:id="@+id/toplayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="">

    <com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView
        android:id="@+id/adview"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/spacer_old"  />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```